# ftp failure from VMS to Unix system

Tags: unix, ftp, openvms, vms

When my customers are trying to transfer the files through ftp system, they are getting this error. It seems like the ftp connection is established however because of some unknown reasons the data is not transferring. This is a connection from VMS system to a Unix server.

```
230 User 1234567 logged in
bin
200 PORT command successful.
hash
Hash mark printing on (1024/hash mark).
put abc.str
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for abc.str
%TCPIP-E-FTP_DATACONF, cannot establish data connection with remote host
-SYSTEM-F-REJECT, connect to network object rejected
226 Transfer complete.
421 Service not available, Remote server has closed the connection
```

Comment: [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) uses two ports. The first, port 21, is used to establish a connection between the client and server and transfers command and status information. The second is used to transfer data and the connection is established when a file transfer is initiated. It appears that the server is refusing to establish the data connection. Perhaps the log on the server offers a clue, e.g. it doesn't care for the client's address, the transfer type (ASCII vs. binary), the transfer mode (active vs. passive), ... .

Comment: Using google "Command Prompt uses Active mode by default.

As you are able to log in (port 21), but not issue commands, it would seem you are not able to establish the Data connection which, using active mode would mean you would have to have a random port open on your firewall to connect to the server's data port of 20." try passive mode? Send: quote pasv

Comment: Thank you folks...moving to passive mode worked

Answer (score 1):

If you use VMS `FTP` then use:

```
set passive on
```

before you start the data connection.

If you use VMS `COPY /FTP` then use:

```
copy /ftp/passive
```

to use passive mode.

For more information, see

```
ftp> help set passive
```

and

```
$ help copy /ftp
```